# Is "'" identical to "\'" as per the C/C++ standard?

Tags: c++, c, escaping, standards, language-specifications

```
int main()
{
    char* str1 = "Tom's cat";
    char* str2 = "Tom\'s cat";
}
```

The code can be compiled with VS 2015.

I just wonder:

**Are both of the two ways compliant to the C and/or the C++ standard?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the `C++11 ISO Standard`

> **§ 2.14.5 String Literals** [lex.string]
>
> ...
>
> **15** Escape sequences and universal-character-names in non-raw string literals have the same meaning as in character literals (2.14.3), except that the single quote ’ is representable either by itself or by the escape
> sequence \’

Answer (score 4):

Yes, within a string literal, both are the same.

The escaped version is required for a character literal:

```
char x = '\'';
```

The standard references are two sources. First, translation phases. From C.11 §5.1.1.2 (C++.11 [**lex.phases**] has similar language):

> 5. **Each source character set member and escape sequence in character constants and string literals is converted to the corresponding member of the execution character set**; if there is no corresponding member, it is converted to an implementation defined member other than the null (wide) character.

Next is in the grammar definition for a character constant and for string literals, which allow for escape sequences. And *simple-escape-sequence* is an escape sequence in the grammar. C.11 §6.4.4.4 defines it (C++.11 [**lex.ccon**] has the same definition):

> *simple-escape-sequence:* one of
>
> ```
> \' \" \? \\
> \a \b \f \n \r \t \v
> ```

Finally, for string literals, the standard specifies the interpretation of characters in the literal is the same as if each were a character constant, and then makes an exception of `'`. From C.11 §6.4.5 (C++.11 [**lex.string**] has similar language):

> The same considerations apply to each element of the sequence in a string literal as if it
>   were in an integer character constant (for a character or UTF−8 string literal) or a wide
>   character constant (for a wide string literal), except that the single-quote `'` is
>   representable either by itself or by the escape sequence `\'`, but the double-quote " shall be represented by the escape sequence `\"`.

Answer (score 2):

`\'` is a valid character escape sequence in both C and C++. Hence, the lines

```
char* str1 = "Tom's cat";
char* str2 = "Tom\'s cat";
```

produce equivalent string literals, both in C and C++.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, they're identical.

From the c++ standard, $2.13.3/7 Character literals [lex.ccon]

> Table 6 — Escape sequences
>
> ```
> new-line         NL(LF) \n
> horizontal tab   HT     \t
> vertical tab     VT     \v
> backspace        BS     \b
> carriage return  CR     \r
> form feed        FF     \f
> alert            BEL    \a
> backslash        \      \\
> question mark    ?      \?
> single quote     ’      \’
> double quote     "      \"
> octal number     ooo    \ooo
> hex number       hhh    \xhhh
> ```